# Spring RequestScope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Please see the example below. I wonder if there will be any difference if I specify the scope or not below. Thanks

```java
@RestController
@RequestScope
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
public class UserResource {

  @GetMapping("/addresscheck")
  public String getAddress() {
    return customer.getAddress();
  }
}


// Here does it matter I define the scope or not? is it still going to be treated as one per request?
@RestController  
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
public class UserResource {

  @GetMapping("/addresscheck")
  public String getAddress() {
    return customer.getAddress();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it does not make any difference. You can check this guide on scopes. It gives good examples of how to use these annotations: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

Comment: What I understand from your question is you want to learn how @RequestScope works, is there anything else your are looking for ?

Answer (score 17):

By default, all Spring managed beans have `singleton` scope. So in your second implementation, only one `UserResource` object will be created by Spring and that will be provided every time a request for the specified URL is to be fulfilled.

However, in the first implementation, since you are annotating `UserResource` with `@RequestScope`, Spring will create a new controller object to serve each request. This means that any state information you may be maintaining in `UserResource` will be lost. All member variables of `UserResource` will also be created anew for each request.

Although I am curious as to why you would want a controller to be request scoped? Could you please share your use-case, if possible?

Here is a good article to read on the subject: [Spring Bean Scopes](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes)